# Access limited for connecting Colab GPU

Tags: neural-network, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am getting this while connecting to Google Colab GPU:

```
You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Colab
```

The last successful connection was about 9 hours ago. What should I do to be able to run my code?

Can anyone please help me?

edit: I saw a question like this and someone suggested running the code again 8 hours later. I tried this but apparently didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is not a strict rule on how much time you should wait.